# simple keyboard input in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried this in Unity with C# but I keep getting compiling error messages

```
void update ()
{ 
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    { 
        transform.Translate(-1,0,0);
    }
}
```

where's the error? any alternative to perform simple movements?

Comment: "where's the error?" is a good question since we have no idea what your error is.  How about including those compiler errors?

Answer (score 4):

Your "update" method needs to be capitalized for Unity to recognize it. Your script will not hook in unless Unity can see that the method name matches one of the ones it's looking for. As for an alternative for simple movements, watch some tutorials on how CharacterControllers work. They have two functions that are pretty easy to use, which are Move, and SimpleMove.

Answer (score 1):

"update" cahnge to Update

and

```
void update () { 

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){ 

//(BAd usage)transform.Translate(-1,0,0);
transform.Translate(new Vector3(-1,0,0));
}
}
```